# Error: RPC request error: cluster version query failed: error sending request for url (http://localhost:8899/): error trying to connect

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rpc, solana-cli, config

```
Error: RPC request error: cluster version query failed: error sending request for url (http://localhost:8899/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 61)
```

[image]

Whenever I try to get `solana balance` or `solana airdrop 2`
I am getting this error.

Also I have a anchor code setup `myepicproject`
After installing the boilerplate when running `anchor test ---skip-local-validator`

I am also getting this error.
Can anybody guide me how to debug it?

Comment: Did you run `solana-test-validator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are skipping the start local validator step, which means you need to turn on your local validator:

```
solana-test-validator
```

Alternatively, if you're looking to do an airdrop and balance check on devnet try:

```
solana config set -u devnet
```

to set your solana instance to devnet.

Here are a couple of guides that may be useful for you:

- https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/getting-started/start-a-solana-local-validator/
- https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/getting-started/a-complete-guide-to-airdropping-test-sol-on-solana/